# How can we add icon with text in form using ngx-fomly/ bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, ngx-formly

Did not get any document/info to **add an icon with text** on the form using ngx-formly/ bootstrap library.

Also trying to add icons using addon but in my project, only two icons display on the form (fa fa-heart and fa fa-edit) other icons are not working like (fa fa-lock), etc. Is there any reason?

Help ..!!

Comment: @aitboudad Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

To add the icon with text in form using ng-fomly/bootstrap, you need to specify the props property associated with that input as shown below:

```
{
    type: 'input',
    key: 'example_input',
    props: {
        required: true,
        label: 'Name',  
        addonLeft: {
            class: 'fa fa-close',
            text: "cancel" 
}
    }
}
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY11c.png)

The props is associated with the control mentioned in 'type' and 'key' is the id of that control.

**You can easily write your text and add icon inside addonLeft or addonRight**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).